# How to animate set of titles of a View using JQuery

Tags: views, theming, javascript

There is a View of latest news title linked to the node page and I need to display them like this [Effect](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/).

I've trying to do it by creating a new template file for my views named:

> views-view-list--latest-news--block.tpl.php

and this is the code I was trying to set to work:

```
<?php print $wrapper_prefix; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
    <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $list_type_prefix; ?>
    <div class="type-wrap">
        <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span> //this is where it shoul be typed...
     </div>

  <?php print $list_type_suffix; ?>
<?php print $wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php
$setOfTitles = "";
foreach($rows as $id=>$row) 
     $setoftitles.="'".$row."'".",";
$setoftitles = rtrim($setoftitles , ','); // to remove the last `,`
print_r ($setoftitles); // and it says I have all of you node titles
?>
<?php print_r($setOfTitles); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var stitles = "<?php $setoftitles;?>"; </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert(stitles); //but its alerts is empty (means variable is not passed to js) 
    $(function(){
        ;
        $("#typed").typed({
            strings: [stitles],
            typeSpeed: 30,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: false,
            contentType: 'html', // or text
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); },
            resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
        });

        $(".reset").click(function(){
            $("#typed").typed('reset');
        });

    });

    function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

    function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }

    </script>
```

but it is not a true answer!! because my alert in js is empty and means I couldn't pass variable form php to js. Where is the problem? and how can I solve it? or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salam :). You need no new Views display type. Create a view of the latest news called it *lnews* and display it in a block, suppose it's machine name is *block_0*. select the titles as the *Fields*. You have to use PHP code inside that block (enable `PHP Filter` module). Use this code

```
 <div class="type-wrap">
        <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span>
</div>
<?php
$views = views_get_view("lnews");
$views->set_display('block_0');
$views->execute();
```

Now to get the titles use this code (to get the accurate code use `kpr($views)`)

```
$setOfTitles = "";
foreach($views->result as $view) 
     $setOfTitles .= $view->node_title."*";
$setOfTitles = rtrim($setOfTitles , "*"); // to remove the last `*`
```

So far you created a string of all of the titles which they are separated by a `*` sign. There is one more step left, Send this variable to a .JS file that contains

```
$(function(){

    $("#typed").typed({
        strings: [HERE IS YOUR STRING],
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        contentType: "html", 
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#typed").typed('reset');
    });
});
```

code, then explode the string to an array and send it to the `strings` object.

To send `$setOfTitles` variable from the above block to the JS file here is a few tutorials

- [How to pass values from php to javascript properly?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60960/how-to-pass-values-from-php-to-javascript-properly)
- [How to send variable from .php file to .js file in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/how-to-send-variable-from-php-file-to-js-file-in-drupal-7)
- [How to pass a PHP variable to javascript in Drupal 7](http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/how-pass-php-variable-javascript-drupal-7)

Now I assume you have successfully sent the variable to .JS file, call it's name `var titles`. use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to convert the string in to an array. Now this code should work:

```
var array_of_titles= titles.split("*"); 
$(function(){
    $("#typed").typed({
        strings: [array_of_titles],
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        contentType: "html", 
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#typed").typed('reset');
    });
});
```

This solution wont link the titles to the node page. The

```
foreach($views->result as $view){ 
     $setOfTitles .= $view->node_title."*";
     $setOFNIDs .= $view->nid."*";
}
```

creates list of node IDs. You can also pass the node IDs to the JS file and with some js processing link the titles to the `/node/nid`.

For example in the JS file instead of creating array of title create array of `<a href="/node/nid">TITLE</a>`

---

**UPDATE:**

Sounds you had problem with sending the `$setOfTitles` variable to the javascript file. Use the following method:

In the PHP code I gave you above add this code

```
drupal_add_js(array('variableName' => $setOfTitles), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/js.js');
```

Create a file in `/js` directory of your theme folder and rename it to `js.js` and in the `js.js` use this code

```
(function($, Drupal){
  Drupal.behaviors.backgroundAnimation = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      alert(Drupal.settings.variableName);
      alert(Drupal.settings.basePath);
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

I tested this solution and it successfully alerted the `variableName` and `basePath`. So just insert the rest of the Javascript code I gave you above in the `(function($, Drupal)` function.

Comment: I used all the solutions told in this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) and this [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29210/how-do-i-add-javascript-specific-for-a-view). but none of them worked for passing variables to .js file

Comment: Could you get the correct value of `$set of titles` in the block?

Comment: when I print it with php it is correct but when I want to show its value with alert in js it is not. I mean the alert is empty

Comment: I updated my answer and let you know how to pass php variable to javascript

Comment: thanks. your answer was really helpful. I use your advises with a bit of changes and creativity and finally it worked.

Comment: khahesh mikonam ;) Don't forget to remove `$` sign in your javascript code

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Drupalist helpes I could do it and it was the code I use to do it:

```
<?php
$views = views_get_view("latest_news");
$views->set_display('block_0');
$views->execute();
$setOfTitles = "";
foreach($views->result as $view) 
     $setOfTitles.= $view->node_title.",";
$setOfTitles = rtrim($setOfTitles , ","); // to remove the last `,`
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sites/all/themes/mycorolla/scripts/typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var $stitles="<?php print $setOfTitles; ?>"; </script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var $test=$stitles.split(","); 
$(function(){
    $("#typed").typed({
        strings: $test,
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: false,
        contentType: "html", 
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#typed").typed('reset');
    });
});
 </script>
 <div class="type-wrap">
<span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span>
</div>
```