# How do I attach JS and CSS on Slick Views

Tags: 7, hooks

I would like to attach a CSS file and a JS library on [Slick Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_views) module from a custom module. Is there a hook function for Slick Views or any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add JavaScript specific for a view?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29210/how-do-i-add-javascript-specific-for-a-view)

Comment: @leymannx The link you provide is the hook function for template.php views. I need to load a JS library when a Slick Views render on a page.

Comment: Which is exactly what this duplicate question answers already. You can place the code in a module as well. If view == my_slick_view, then fire drupal_add_js/css.

Comment: @leymannx This function target a specific view name. I have a multisite that contains 100+ sites. It will be an issue if anyone create a new slick views with different views name.

Comment: Then check for other attributes then the name. Depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up from @leymannx (and copy/pasting from the linked answer) here's a more spelled-out solution:

You could use the [`template_preprocess_views_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7) hook to do this:

```
function THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = &$vars['view'];
  // Make sure it's the correct view
  if ($view->name == 'my_slick_view') {
    // add needed javascript
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'your-theme') . '/your-js.js');
    // add needed stylesheet
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'your-theme') . '/your-css.css');
  }
}
```